# Lucene.net can run on 64 bit OS?

Tags: asp.net-core, lucene.net, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm planning to use lucene.net for one of the .net core projects, but before that, I would like to know if anybody has used lucene.net on 64-bit OS. I hope it is compatible.

Comment: I think you could check it:https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net/3.0.3

Comment: They have not mentioned anything about 32bit or 64bit